# How do you create Backbone views with an 'el' that was dynamically created?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have two views -- an OverlayView and a StoryView. The StoryView needs to get appended to the OverlayView (both are created dynamically).  I create the #overlay div dynamically in the OverlayView, but when I set the 'el' of the StoryView to #overlay, this.$el of StoryView is an empty array.  The #overlay div definitely exists in the DOM by the time the StoryView is created.

How do I get the StoryView to recognize the dyanmically created #overlay as its 'el'?  Am I correct in assuming the 'el' should be the 'parent' container to which the view is appended?  Should the 'el' of the OverlayView actually be '#overlay'?

**OverlayView:**

```
OverlayView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),

    events: {
        'click #film': 'hideOverlay'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.append('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        return this;
    }
});
```

**StoryView:**

```
var StoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#overlay'),

    events: {
        'click .close': 'closeStory'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.$el); // Returns empty array []
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that your `StoryView` `el` should simply be a selector — not a jQuery object. That will cause Backbone to try to retrieve the object (which does not yet exist) at the time you specify `el`. Just change `el: $('#overlay')` to `el: '#overlay'`. You might also do the same for `$('body')` in your first view, since it's not necessary. Just always use selectors instead of jQuery objects and you'll be fine.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/joshleitzel/dzQuB/).

Comment: You're right, I was unnecessarily wrapping that in a jQuery object. Thanks!